# User posting with multiple identities similar worthless questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

I got the feeling these two users, [@kate-smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4036872/kate-smith) and [@sarah-smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4036854/sarah-smith), are the same user (there could be more, but these are the two I've spotted).

That in itself isn't a problem, but when you look at the questions they continue to post, the fact they ignore all efforts to help them I can't help but feel this is just spam.

They are continually posting in the [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) queue questions about code (that are clearly custom wrappers and both myself and others have pointed this out).

- [Using execute scalar to set a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26120558/692942)

  > **Some comments**
  >
  > This loosely looks like [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) and not [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) but `ExecuteScalar()` is similar to a [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) method in `System.Data`. In this case I would say `ExecuteScalar()` and `NewIntParam()` are both UDFs *(User Defined Functions)* and you need to show the code for them (they will be defined in the asp page or in dependent files that are linked via `#include` syntax), there is nothing built in to Classic ASP like that. –  Lankymart 20 hours ago
- [Classic asp parameter length causes 'String or binary data would be truncated.' error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26137414/692942)
- [ExecuteReader without parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25831212/692942)

  > **Some comments**
  >
  > `ExecuteReader()` is no built in asp-classic function I've ever heard of which is probably why @ShadowWizard deems it off topic. Perhaps you can show the code for `ExecuteReader()` and `NewIntParam()` *(possibly in your page or in an `#include` file that the page is dependant on)*. Remember not to confuse asp.net methods with Classic ASP coding. –  Lankymart Sep 14 at 14:58
- [ExecuteNonQuery Object Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25819881/692942)

  > **Some comments**
  >
  > Classic ASP has no native "ExecuteNonQuery" function or method. Ask whoever wrote the code where this method is defined and add it to your code. –  Shadow Wizard Sep 14 at 11:37

Bearing in mind that there are no such built-in functions as `ExecuteScalar()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()`, `ExecuteReader()`, `NewIntParam()`, or `NewTextParam()` in [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic), it's almost like some [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) developer has decided to write a load of wrappers for [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic). Without any of that UDF code we are helpless to help, but they continue to post similar questions (different titles, different users).

What is the best course of action to take?

Comment: Flag the posts, add a explanation of the situation in the flags.

Comment: @Cerbrus: unless someone is evading a ban, there is no point in flagging.

Comment: Just downvote and move on. The accounts will hit question ban territory soon enough.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is that perhaps why they keep creating new accounts?

Comment: @Lankymart: perhaps. Are the posts dupes perhaps? Or have other striking similarities? Then flag and let a moderator sort that out.

Comment: Not sure if impressed or aggravated by use of "bespoke"

Comment: Didn't mean to offend @Will is that any better? :p

Comment: @Will I don't see why one could not be simultaneously impressed and aggravated.

Comment: Bespoke code?  I'm not sure if I should be enraged by a hipsterization of development or impressed by the audacity of the use...

Comment: Looks like [meta-tag:status-completed] to me, one of the accounts is now a 404, with the question gone too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just downvote the question, perhaps vote to close the question as off-topic if not enough information is present to help them, and *move on*. The quality control throttles (a severe rate limit and then the question ban) will take care of the rest.

If you have suspicions that multiple accounts are being used to circumvent the limits set, then you can flag a post and explain this to a moderator (pick the *Other* option). They can then investigate with the tools they have.

Comment: Ok, I've flagged the questions for moderator attention and included a link to this post.

Comment: @Lankymart I would stress the **explain** part. Make sure to let the mods know *why* you are flagging.

Comment: @codeMagic Hopefully i've done that, referred back to this post.